# Server TCP provider has stopped listening on port [ 1433 ] due to a failure. Error: 0x2726

Tags: sql-server

Recently on one of our SQL Server we have faced below issue

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        MSSQLSERVER
>   Date:          6/28/2017 12:33:51 AM
>   Event ID:      26040
>   Task Category: Server
>   Level:         Error
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>   Computer:      Host1
>
> Description:
>   Server TCP provider has stopped listening on port [ 1433 ] due to a failure. Error: 0x2726, state: 1. The server will automatically attempt to reestablish listening.

Various links https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/44a4b4b2-f418-460e-805d-85e445db982f/how-to-resolve-this?forum=sqlgetstarted

Related to this error suggests that the most probable cause for this issue is Higher Disk I/O. but in our case, we have verified that Disk I/O which remains always normal on this server, we have reviewed the data from New relic as well when this incident was occurred.

Is there anyone having any idea about what should we investigate beside Disk I/O? as this is not being cause in our case

Comment: This is the windows event log. Is there any more information in the SQl Server log?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.